# Avoid chained numbers when printing lists

Tags: python, list, chained

The code that I created generate a list with 15 numbers, from combinations, so after sorting it it's possible to see that some sequences comes with a lot of numbers chained like:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 15, 16, 20]
```

I'm trying to think a way to control it and print only lists with maximum 4 chained numbers:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 15, 16, 20]

(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11) >>>> 11 Chained numbers: 1 to 11.
So it won't be stored in file.txt.


[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 16, 17, 18, 19, 22, 23]

(1, 2, 3) >>>> 3 chained, OK
(6, 7, 8, 9) >>>> 4 chained, OK
(11, 12) >>>> 2 chained, OK
(16, 17, 18, 19) >>>> 4 chained, OK
(22,23) 2 chained, OK. 
So this list will be stored in the file
```

Could you guys give me an idea? A light?

Code that I created, it generate a file with all possible combinations of 15 numbers from a list of 25:

```
import itertools
my_file = open('file.txt', 'w')

ALL_25 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]

for subset in itertools.combinations(ALL_25, 15):
    sort_subsets = sorted(subset)
    my_file.write("{0}\n".format(sort_subsets))  
    print(sort_subsets)
my_file.close()
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. For example, if the input is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 20]` should the output be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 20]` or `[1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 20]` or something else? Do you want to highlight the "jumps"? `[1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 6, 7, 8, 9, 20]` or `[1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 9, 20]`?

Comment: I see, something went wrong when I posted it. Let me explain, I have a code that generate a lots of 15 combinations from 25 numbers, than after it save all combinations in a txt file.

Comment: So it creates lists like [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15] what I want to do is eliminate the combinations with chained numbers like above, something that will just save the combinations that have at maximous 4 chained numbers like: [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11, 12, 15, 16, 17, 18, 21, 25] see, (1, 2, 3) has 3 numbers in chain, (5, 6) has 2, (9, 10, 11, 12) has 4. so if there is a list with 5 or more numbers in chain like (9, 10, 11, 12, 13) it will be eliminated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can convert the chain to its difference between consecutive elements it is easier to identify incremental sequences i.e, `[1,2,3,4,7,8]` gets converted to `[1,1,1,3,1]`. Further by converting it into a string it is easier to search for the pattern `111`.

```
import numpy as np                                          
import re                                                   

def validate(seq):                                          
    stl = "".join(np.diff(seq).astype(str))                 
    for x in re.findall("[1]+",stl):                        
        if len(x)>3:                                        
            return False                                    
    return True                                             

print validate([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 15, 16, 20])
print validate([1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 16, 17, 18, 19, 22, 23])
```

**output**

```
False
True
```

Comment: But it seems to short the list, what I'm doing here is generating a txt file with all possible combinations with some numbers, than what I want to do is to remove these sequences of numbers that is chained, to reduce the amount of combinations in the file. So my code runs nice and generate a list per line in the file, each list has different numbers from the others, so I just want to 'remove' (to not save it in the file) the lists that have more than four numbers chained.

Comment: @CairoLievore, Are you saying you have more than one lists and want to remove all the lists which have sequential numbers in them? Could you update your question then?

Comment: Almost there, my code generate the lists, so I'm trying to figure it out how to check each generated list before it print out and save in the file

Comment: @CairoLievore, Since you're extracting combinations and order is not important here you can try sampling elements from your list using `random.sample()`

Comment: the order is not important, but it can't repeat numbers. Take a look at the code that I created, run it in python idle, it will generate a lot of lists and will store it in file.txt. so I just want to remove the lists with chained numbers, this is important and will eliminate a lot of unnecessary lists.

Comment: the code that I updated in the final part of the question, the on that generate the combinations is just an example of what I'm doing, the real code that i'm using generate all possible combinations from 3 different lists without repeating numbers, so, now I just need to figure it out how to eliminate the lists with more than 4 numbers chained.

Comment: @CairoLievore, Check the updated answer. `validate()` function would return False if sequence length is greater than 4

Comment: thank you man, the code work nice now. Now let me ask you another thing, when it run validate() it return true for the line with 4 chained numbers, see the list validate([1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 16, 17, 18, 19, 22, 23]) it has two sequences of four (6, 7, 8, 9) and (16, 17, 18, 19), so is it possible to return True   for sequences with only one sequence of four, if there is more than one it return false? like print validate(2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20, 22, 23) >>>> there is only one (5, 6, 7, 8) with for, so it return True.